# Do chickens always lay eggs?

Tags: reproduction, nutrition, ornithology

[http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hühnerei](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%BChnerei) says it takes up to 24 h for a chicken to produce an egg.

Is that dependent on the chickens nutrition, i.e., if it does not get enough food or the wrong kind, meaning it can survive on the food but it does not have everything to produce an egg?

Do we have data on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short; yes. It depends on the breed (not all lay up to 1 egg/day), the age of the bird and on nutrition. High yielding breeds of chicken are e.g. dependent on supplements of calcium to be able to produce new shells rapidly (e.g. in the form of ground-up shells). Some information on the nutrient requirements of chicken can be found at [*Feeding the Laying Hen*](http://www.hyline.com/aspx/redbook/redbook.aspx?s=6&p=53). Egg production will also fluctuate over the year, and will generally decrease e.g. during molting, since energy and nutrients are then diverted to the production of feathers (see info at e.g. [*The Poultry site*](http://www.thepoultrysite.com/articles/450/several-reasons-why-your-hens-may-stop-laying-eggs)).

Comment: Ok. That means they always lay eggs, it can take just a little longer sometimes depending on resources available to the chicken. I guess it might stop at some point, when they are really starved.

Comment: They will stop laying entirely if severely malnourished, but may also stop completely during molting.

Answer (score 1):

every 24 hours they can lay an egg new young chickens that are for the first time laying eggs could possibly  but there is no breed that lays two eggs a day. and note it might be about a year for some to start so don't think if there not producing eggs there is something wrong, my chickens didn't lay eggs (note i have Plymouth Rock chickens) and they didn't lay until they were about a year. they may stop for molting or stop every here and there randomly and this is important to them laying eggs they need lots of calcium.

Comment: rockinboy3303 please use standard grammar while writing As and Qs. In Eng language sentences start with capital letters.